# Magento 2.1.2 offline install extension

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2, offline-mode

Is there any way to upload and install an magento 2.1.2 extension in offline mode without magento connect?

Base on my official development station, I did not have a internet connection to use composer or magento connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution**

You can upload you extension file in the below path:

```
<magento_installation_path>/app/code/
```

after that, you must run below command to register extension:

```
php <magento_installation_path>/bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and sometime require to recompile magento with below command.

```
php <magento_installation_path>/bin/magento setup:di:compile
```